# Why was a question on an inability to install a commonly used software tool closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

I know several people that ran into the following issue but it was closed for some reason that I can't understand.

[Error installing RMySQL on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487855/error-installing-rmysql-on-os-x)

It's about a common software tool, it's about installing the tool, and the question was answerable. What about it caused it to be closed?

Comment: It appears the closers are not familiar with the R language and thought it's not programming. Not familiar with R either but as it's programming language and the question appears to be valid voted to reopen it.

Comment: Looks good to me.  Voted to reopen.

Comment: Maybe users with less than X score on specific tag shouldn't be allowed to close questions with that tag.

Comment: That would cause a lot of cruft to build up, @ShaWizDowArd. Doesn't take a background in R (or Ruby or Razor or REST) to smell a bad question in that tag.

Comment: If this happens to you again in the future, feel free to drop by [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public) and ask the R folks specifically. (Just like asking on Meta, we might disagree, but at least you'll be asking people who know R, if that makes you feel better.)

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I agree, but knowledge in the tag area does make identifying bad questions _easier_. I'm always much more cautious about voting to close on questions outside R.

Comment: I'm with you, @joran, and do the same. Coincidentally, I stay further away from R than I do other tags that I'm not familiar with. Like Magento, I've found that R questions that appear too high-level and broad, often end up being just fine.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta [se] did a fantastic job promoting Win8 on programmers. Products like R that are gaining popularity I think we should give the benefit of the doubt. Thanks everyone for reopening this one.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion, everyone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In many cases that I've seen in my time on SO/SE, questions are sometimes closed through obscurity rather than knowledge - In this case, by obscurity, I mean *a lack of understanding or appreciation* around a particular programming language and environment rather than it's direct usage.

Despite the merits of reputation and the privileges that come with it on SO, some developers with experience in a particular language comment, downvote and close questions readily and largely because such questions:

- Can't be answered with ease
- Are considered an edge-case
- They feel it's off-topic because it's to do with installation
- It's using a platform/OS that they don't know
- They're burning their way through the queue for badges

Sometimes, when people see the word **installation**, they often think it's more applicable on [superuser](http://superuser.com) (or different) and close it as off-topic. When in fact, there are SO users who will perhaps have direct experience of what you're looking for and an ability to provide you with a great answer and one which can be relied upon by others in the future.

Often, those with more in-depth experience of particular languages know, by default, that the use of a language isn't just how it's used - but it's installation, linkage, dependencies and more; Something that ***in this case*** is directly evidenced by [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16490653/1714488) that was provided and that you accepted - It came from a high-rep user who has answered more than [**2,000 questions**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855677/dwin?tab=tags) on [r](/questions/tagged/r)...

Answer (score 1):

No one really knows.  Possibly the closers thought it looked more like a superuser installation question.  In any case, the question has been re-opened, probably thanks to the publicity from this meta question.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote.  I think the user was implicitly asking "should it have been?" and I could easily see this hovering around forever without any answers. I think other answer is better but this question needed to look resolved.